# Shortest source to destination path

Tags: c++, algorithm, breadth-first-search

I am trying to find the minimum number of steps required to reach to the destination from the source. For this, I am using BFS algorithm of graph traversal. I think I have applied the correct logic for BFS algorithm but I am not getting the correct answer when the destination node cannot be reached from source. Can, anyone check what I have done wrong in the code.

```
int shortestDistance(int N, int M, vector<vector<int>> A, int X, int Y) {
        
        vector<vector<int>>visited(N, vector<int>(M, 0));
        
        visited[0][0] = 1;
        queue<pair<int, int>>qe;
        pair<int, int>pr;
        pr.first = 0;
        pr.second = 0;
        
        qe.push(pr);
        queue<int>count;
        count.push(0);
        
        while(!qe.empty()){
            pair<int, int>pr1 = qe.front();
            qe.pop();
            
            int a = pr1.first;
            int b = pr1.second;
            int cnt = count.front();
            count.pop();
            if(a == X && b == Y){
                return cnt;
            }
            
            if(a-1 >= 0 && A[a][b] == 1 && visited[a-1][b] == 0){
                visited[a-1][b] = 1;
                pair<int, int>pr2;
                pr2.first = a-1;
                pr2.second = b;
                qe.push(pr2);
                
                count.push(cnt+1);
            }
            
            if(a+1 < N && A[a][b] == 1 && visited[a+1][b] == 0){
                visited[a+1][b] = 1;
                pair<int, int>pr2;
                pr2.first = a+1;
                pr2.second = b;
                qe.push(pr2);
                count.push(cnt+1);
            }
            
            
            if(b-1 >= 0 && A[a][b] == 1 && visited[a][b-1] == 0){
                visited[a][b-1] = 1;
                pair<int, int>pr2;
                pr2.first = a;
                pr2.second = b-1;
                qe.push(pr2);
                count.push(cnt+1);
            }
            
            if(b+1 < M && A[a][b] == 1 && visited[a][b+1] == 0){
                visited[a][b+1] = 1;
                pair<int, int>pr2;
                pr2.first = a;
                pr2.second = b+1;
                qe.push(pr2);
                count.push(cnt+1);
            }
        }
        
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Start with the smallest input set that leads to the wrong answer. Then [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your program to find out when and where and why things go wrong.

Comment: You shouldn't mark visited of the next locations when checking the current location. Only mark a location as visited AFTER it has been checked

Comment: You've got `A[a][b]` in all four `if` statements.

Comment: changing A[a][b] in all four if statements solved the error. Thank you